# MS Graph API - How to query additional pages

Tags: azure, powershell, pagination, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-intune

I'm unsure as to how to query additional pages. Through some guides I've seen I've cobbled together the following but am only getting the first 1000 results (expecting a number close to 15000). I seem unable to capture the @odata.nextLink value to add to the loop.

```
$DeviceList = @()    
$URI = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/deviceManagement/managedDevices?`$filter=contains(OperatingSystem,'iOS')&?`$select=serialNumber,Id"

if ($Null -ne $URI) 
    {
    $GetDevices = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $Headers -Uri $URI
    $DeviceList += $GetDevices.value
    $URI = $GetDevices.'@Odata.nextLink'
    }

$DeviceList | Export-Csv C:\Users\######\Downloads\Test.csv -Force -Append
```

Comment: Shouldn't `if ($Null -ne $URI)` be a `while` or `do` loop ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To handle [paging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/paging?tabs=http) you can use a [`do` loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_do?view=powershell-7.4) re-assigning the value of `$uri.'@odata.nextLink'` to a variable and the loop *break* condition can be *while there is a `nextLink`*:

```
$uri = 'htts://graph.microsoft.com/.....'

& {
    do {
        $uri = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $Headers -Uri $uri
        $uri.Value
        $uri = $uri.'@Odata.nextLink'
    } while($uri)
} | Export-Csv path\to\export.csv -NoTypeInformation
```